# Dynamically set backbone collection url returns models without attributes

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, backbone.js-collections

I have a backbone mobile application that is tied to a Rails web service. All models of other objects are loaded and displayed correctly, but this particular one does not. The issue I am having is that `Item` gets created, but does not load the attributes. I have confirmed correct json output of the rails api. The difference between this collection and all other collections of this application is that this collection has a parentID that must be used in the url to load the correct items (`category_id`).

Now... the funny thing is that if I remove the `{category_id: options.attributes[0].category_id}` argument to the constructor call of `ItemCollectionView` and hard code a `category_id` directly into the url, it works! (however I need to assign this dynamically based on the category of the parent view.

Here are my classes:

```
export class ItemCollectionView extends Backbone.View {
    public template: string;
    public collection: itemsImport.Items;

    constructor(options?: Backbone.ViewOptions){
        this.collection = new itemsImport.Items({category_id: options.attributes[0].category_id});
        super(options);
    }
    ...
    public addOne(item: itemImport.Item): void{
        var view: itemItemImport.ItemItemView = new itemItemImport.ItemItemView({el: this.el, model: item});
        //Breakpoint right here shows that item.attributes.id = undefined
        view.render();
    }
}

export class Items extends Backbone.Collection {
    public url: string;

    constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any){
        this.url = 'http://localhost:3000/categories/' + attributes.category_id + '/items';
        this.model = itemImport.Item;
        super(attributes, options);
    }
}
```

In my debugging I can confirm that:

```
options.attributes[0].category_id == 1;
```

and

```
this.url == 'http://localhost:3000/categories/1/items';
```

and the response from that url is:

```
[{"id":1,"category_id":1,"title":"Item 1","description":null,"active":true,"comment":null,"extra":null,"deleted":"0","url":"http://localhost:3000/categories/1/items/1.json"},{"id":2,"category_id":1,"title":"Item 2","description":null,"active":true,"comment":null,"extra":null,"deleted":"0","url":"http://localhost:3000/categories/1/items/2.json"}]
```

which you can see is a correct json response.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? || What is the correct way to dynamically pass variables into collections to set the correct url at runtime?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer selected will work if using javascript, but if using TypeScript the compiler will complain that `url` must be a property, not a method. The solution I found (which will work in javascript as well) is to set the `url` argument on the `fetch()` method of the collection like below

```
export class ItemCollectionView extends Backbone.View {
    public template: string;
    public collection: itemsImport.Items;

    constructor(options?: Backbone.ViewOptions){
        this.collection = new itemsImport.Items({category_id: options.attributes[0].category_id});
        super(options);
    }

    public initialize(options?:any): void {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
        this.collection.fetch({url: this.collection.seturl(options.attributes[0].category_id)});
    }

    ...

}
```

I hope this helps future users looking for this functionality in Backbone

Answer (score 1):

Define `url` as function like in second case [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url)

```
var Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return this.document.url() + '/notes';
    }
});
```

And check network tab if you really load correct url.

Comment: When using typescript `url` must be a property, not a method. I found a solution and will post it soon. There is a `url` option on the fetch method of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a dynamic `url` property to your Backbone model in your Typescript code. This would be better than using the `url` parameter in all your calls to `fetch()`.

You could either do it using an ECMAScript 5 getter:

```
export class Items extends Backbone.Collection {
    get url(): string {
        return '/categories/' + this.get('category_id') + '/items';
    }

    constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any){
        this.model = itemImport.Item;
        super(attributes, options);
    }
}
```

or by setting it directly on the `prototype`:

```
export class Items extends Backbone.Collection {
    constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any){
        this.model = itemImport.Item;
        super(attributes, options);
    }
}
Items.prototype.url = function() { 
    return '/categories/' + this.get('category_id') + '/items'; 
};
```

The second solution will work on all browser.